# Magento 2.3.3 Error Beyond the blank screen

Tags: installation, permissions, apache-http-server, centos, magento

I've been trying to run the Magento Setup for months.  I've installed on my own Centos 8 server and met the pre-requisites.  I got the common white screen of death in the browser.  I've been able to puke the error to the screen and got the following garbage ...

> Fatal error: Uncaught ReflectionException: Class Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection\Proxy does not exist in /var/www/html/Magento/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Reader/ClassReader.php:19 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/Magento/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Reader/ClassReader.php(19): ReflectionClass->__construct('Magento\Framewo...') #1 /var/www/html/Magento/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Definition/Runtime.php(49): Magento\Framework\Code\Reader\ClassReader->getConstructor('Magento\Framewo...') #2 /var/www/html/Magento/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(48): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Definition\Runtime->getParameters('Magento\Framewo...') #3 /var/www/html/Magento/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(70): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\Framewo...') #4 /var/www/html/Magento/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(160): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('Magento\F in /var/www/html/Magento/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Reader/ClassReader.php on line 19

I tried as suggested messing with my permissions.  That has not helped yet.  Here are my current permissions ...

```
drwxrwxrwx.  4 apache root      110 Nov 10 21:05 app

-rwxrwxrwx.  1 apache root      150 Nov  9 20:40 auth.json.sample

drwxrwxrwx.  2 apache root       38 Nov  9 20:40 bin

-rwxrwxrwx.  1 apache root   619839 Nov  9 20:40 CHANGELOG.md

-rwxrwxrwx.  1 apache root     2309 Sep 19 12:30 composer.json

-rwxrwxrwx.  1 apache root   743421 Nov  9 20:40 composer.lock

-rwxrwxrwx.  1 apache root      650 Nov  9 20:40 COPYING.txt

drwxrwxrwx.  5 apache root       63 Nov  9 20:40 dev

drwxrwxrwx.  2 apache root       23 Nov  9 20:40 generated

-rwxrwxrwx.  1 apache root       57 Nov  9 20:40 grunt-config.json.sample

-rwxrwxrwx.  1 apache root     2994 Nov  9 20:40 Gruntfile.js.sample

-rwxrwxrwx.  1 apache root        9 Oct 28 12:55 index.html

-rwxrwxrwx.  1 apache root     1370 Nov  9 20:40 index.php

-rwxrwxrwx.  1 apache root       21 Oct 27 19:27 index.php_tester

-rwxrwxrwx.  1 apache root       21 Oct 27 19:27 info.php

drwxrwxrwx.  4 apache root       50 Nov  9 20:40 lib

-rwxrwxrwx.  1 apache root    10376 Nov  9 20:40 LICENSE_AFL.txt

-rwxrwxrwx.  1 apache root    10364 Nov  9 20:40 LICENSE.txt

-rwxrwxrwx.  1 apache root     5742 Nov  9 20:40 nginx.conf.sample

-rwxrwxrwx.  1 apache root     1416 Nov  9 20:40 package.json.sample

drwxrwxrwx.  2 apache root       58 Nov  9 20:40 phpserver

drwxrwxrwx.  6 apache root      182 Nov  9 20:40 pub

-rwxrwxrwx.  1 apache root      700 Nov  9 20:40 SECURITY.md

drwxrwxrwx.  7 apache root      115 Nov  9 20:40 setup

-rwxrwxrwx.  1 apache root       43 Nov 10 17:19 test.html

drwxrwxrwx.  7 apache root      191 Oct 31 18:11 update

drwxrwxrwx.  2 apache apache      6 Nov 11 19:42 var

drwxrwxrwx. 76 apache root     4096 Nov  9 20:48 vendor
```

Comment: Just a comment, but [Magento.SE](https://magento.stackexchange.com/) might be a better place to ask this. It is dedicated to Magento and has (answered) questions similar to this one.

Comment: OK.  I'll try to edit where I posted.